# RavenDB Lets encrypt security mode failed

Tags: ravendb, lets-encrypt, ravendb-studio

I am trying to set the IP addresses and ports and i have tried a couple.

> 127.0.0.1 on port 8080
>
> 127.0.0.1 on port 3000

And i try to continue and it gives me a configuration failed error (See Below)

> Setting up RavenDB in Let's Encrypt security mode failed.

**What am i doing wrong?**

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ? What is the exception?  How do you set the IPs (config file?) ? Did you read the docs ?

https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/start/installation/setup-wizard

Comment: @garay i have looked at the docs and in the studio of ravendb i have to set my license and so on then i go to try it ask for my IP/host name TCP and / or HTTPS port and it lets me do the same for external and i do so but it gives me the error. I would have to try again to see what exception it gives me

Comment: There is nothing to do without the exception. I would recommend you to re-setup ravendb and go over the setup wizard again and follow the documentation. If you get an exception, please post it along with the stacktrace.

Comment: @garay there was an exception but I’d have to get it. I’ve been to busy to post it but I will

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when trying to install the RaveDB server with an SSL certificate but this is not indicated. Restart the installation and select without certificate or add some SSL certificate